# c# объявление и использование в разных частях кода

Tags: c#, winforms

Портянка кода.
Есть несколько кнопок и на каждой приходится делать: "Загрузить файл"... т.к. 
иначе выдает ошибку на дальнейшее использование doc.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"SomeFile.xml");
```

Как 1 раз загрузить файл и использовать сколько угодно раз на кнопках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private XDocument _doc;

public XDocument doc 
{
     get
     {
         if (_doc == null)
         {
             var tmp = LoadFromFile();
             if(tmp != null)
               _doc = tmp;
             else
               генерируете исключение 
         }
         return _doc;
     }
}

 private XDocument LoadFromFile()
 {
     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

     openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
     openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
     openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
     openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

     if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         try
         {
            return XDocument.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);

            return null;
         }
     }

     return null;
}
```

Comment: Мне бы ваши возможности ))

Comment: Подскажи как openfiledialog прикрутить к этому коду вместо конкретного файла?

Comment: @Андрей вместо свойства сделайте метод, в который будете передавать путь к файлу. Тогда нажатие первой кнопки загрузит документ, а все остальные кнопки будут пользоваться уже загруженным документом.

Comment: Изменил код, где вызывает OpenFileDialog при первом обращении к методу

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться [ленивой загрузкой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private Lazy<XDocument> _doc = new Lazy<XDocument>(() => XDocument.Load(@"SomeFile.xml"));

public XDocument doc 
{
     get
     {
         return _doc.Value;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы в каждом обработчике кнопки объявляете локальную переменную для хранения документа. Вынесите ее в приватное поле формы и загружайте XML из файла, например, по событию `Load` формы. Сохранение можно повесить либо на событие `Close`, либо делать периодически по таймеру, если файл может потребоваться кому-то еще.

Comment: вот так делаю `var d = new OpenFileDialog()`

Comment: @Андрей `OpenFileDialog` нужен только для выбора нужного файла. Открытие как таковое он не производит, хотя и предоставляет методы для создания потока. По большому счету, не важно в каком событии вы будете загружать документ в память и каким образом укажете открываемый файл, вкомпилированной строкой, диалогом, или параметром командной строки. И если посмотреть внимательно на решения предложенные ранее, там тоже используется поле вместо переменной, только на этом не акцентировано внимание.